# Singed integers are not saving properly?

Tags: magento-1.9, save, varchar

I have a custom table with column 'discount_percentage', which is a signed integer.

e.g. +5 , -2 likewise

I have defined the data type as Varchar for this field. But it's not saving the value properly. When I save +10 it will only save 10. But I want it to be as +10.

I tried by enclosing the single quotes. But didn't work.

Please can anyone explain what am I missing here?

Comment: What is the input validation set to?

Comment: No validation has been set

Comment: Not sure about the cause without seeing the attribute dump, but since this is at max 200 values, you could implement this as dropdown. So single select for the input.

Comment: Anyway I was able to save minus values (e.g. -4 ) in database under the type of VARCHAR. But strings like +3, +4 still cannot save

Comment: Check what the default input validation is and check for proper encoding of the value. A plus can be interpreted as space. However, if you can save negative values and the value is not zero, then it's positive, so the problem can be worked around.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that javascript verification input has absolute value numeric transformation, or use to save as `(string)$discount_percentage` in php

Comment: Tried. This doesn't work

Comment: variable is from url ? , check if utf-8 table format, and variable php, or check if has white spaces